# Purchase Status of an In-App purchase is 'null'

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase

I am working on in-app purchases for my flutter app, using the official [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) plugin. After implementing the first IAP I created a test-track and a non-consumable product in the Play Console and added myself as a tester. The purchase completed succesfully and the money got transfered from my bank account, but the UI didn't change as expected. I figured out that the 'PurchaseStatus' of the purchase is 'null', which should be 'pending', 'purchased' or 'error'. How is this possible?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @vincentnyanga has any of you managed to figure out why this is happening? I’m kinda stuck